# getopt command line arguments for file python

Tags: python, file, arguments, getopt

I have to read a file from command line arguments using `getopt` in Python and if I keep `-file` argument then I couldn't switch the optional arguments order.

**Example:**

With out File:

`python apple.py -debug -help` and vise versa  (works)

**With File:**

1) `python apple.py **-file abc.txt -debug -help**`

(it doesn't work - my requirement)

2) `python apple.py **-help -file apple.txt**`   (works)

3)   `python apple.py **-debug -file apple.txt**`  (works)

I want the options to be behave independently - in any order I pass `-file` then it should read file.

My code implemented like this (apple.py):

```
 opts , args = getopt.getopt ( sys.argv[1:], "file help debug")

        for opt , arg in opts:
            if opt in ("-f"):
                for line, lines in enumerate(fileinput.input(args)):
                    if line == 2:
                        print(lines)

            elif opt in ("-h"):
                print("it is just a help")

            elif opt in ("-d"):
                print ( "Debug is On" )
```

`python apple.py -file abc.txt -debug -help`  (doesn't work)

`python apple.py -file abc.txt -debug` (doesn't work)

I keep get an error which says:

> No File or Directory found for -debug

Comment: `fileinput.input(args)` --> `fileinput.input(arg)`?

Comment: i tried fileinput.input(arg) but no it doesn't read file ..
fileinput.input(args) --> got me the lines from file when passed

python apple.py -file abc.txt

Comment: Try printing out the contents of `opts` and `args` and make sure you're getting the output you expect.

Comment: yes getopt does work as i wanted i.e. all options are independent but the moment i put file read code into it then .. all options are no more independent .. 

if i want the file to get red then i should pass like below 

python apple.py **-help -file apple.txt**